# Почему select не кликается?

Tags: html, css, css3

Доброго времени друзья! Делаю форму обратной связи со вкладками, посредством radio button
в общем select у меня стал не кликабельным , в голову не приходит почему. вот ссылка на онлайн редактор http://jsbin.com/yoq/7/edit (Пункт 1 который)

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;  
}
.tabbed{
  font: 1em 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position:relative;
}
.tabbed > input{
  display: none;
}
.tabbed > label{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .3s;
}
.tabbed > label:hover,
.tabbed > input:checked +label{
  background: #4EC6DE;
}
.tabs{
  clear:both;
}
.tabs > div{
  width: 800px;
  position:absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 2px solid #4EC6DE;
  padding: 30px 30px 40px;
}
#tabNav1:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(1),
#tabNav2:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(2),
#tabNav3:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(3),
#tabNav4:checked ~ .tabs > div:nth-of-type(4){
  opacity:1;
  z-index: 1000;
}
td{
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.0/normalize.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="tabbed">
    <input type="radio" name='tabs' id="tabNav1" checked>
    <label for="tabNav1">Заявка</label>
    <input type="radio" name='tabs' id="tabNav2">
    <label for="tabNav2">Задать вопрос</label>
    <input type="radio" name='tabs' id="tabNav3">
    <label for="tabNav3">Заказать звонок</label>
    <input type="radio" name='tabs' id="tabNav4">
    <label for="tabNav4">Оставить отзыв</label>
    <div class="tabs">
      <div>
        <form action="">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Раздел* :</td>
              <td>
                <select name="razdely">
                  <option value="fasadpanel">Фасадные панели</option>
                  <option value="sayding">Сайдинг</option>
                   <option value="soffity">Соффиты</option>
                   <option value="ventfasady">Вент. фасады</option>
                   <option value="krovlya">Кровля</option>
                   <option value="sandvich">Сэндвич панели</option>
                   <option value="vodostochka">Водосточная система</option>
                   <option value="drenazh">Дренажные каналы</option>
                   <option value="bvd">Быстровозводимые дома</option>
                   <option value="angary">Ангары</option>
                   <option value="profnastil">Профнастил</option>
                   <option value="profil">Профиль</option>
                   <option value="fibrovolokno">Фиброволокно</option>
                   <option value="parogidro">Парогидроизоляция</option>
                   <option value="zabori">Заборы</option>
                   <option value="metall">Металл</option>
                   <option value="osb">OSB-3</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>Город :</td>
              <td>
                <select name="goroda" id="">
                  <option value="">Алматы</option>
                  <option value="">Астана</option>
                  <option value="">Шымкент</option>
                  <option value="">Караганда</option>
                  <option value="">Актобе</option>
                  <option value="">Тараз</option>
                  <option value="">Павлодар</option>
                  <option value="">Усть-Каменогорск</option>
                  <option value="">Семей</option>
                  <option value="">Костанай</option>
                  <option value="">Уральск</option>
                  <option value="">Петропавловск</option>
                  <option value="">Кызылорда</option>
                  <option value="">Атырау</option>
                  <option value="">Актау</option>
                  <option value="">Темиртау</option>
                  <option value="">Кокшетау</option>
                  <option value="">Талдыкорган</option>
                  <option value="">Экибастуз</option>
                  <option value="">Рудный</option>
                  <option value="">Другой...</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Имя* :</td>
              <td><input type="text" value='Иванов Иван Иванович'></td>
              <td>Телефон* :</td>
              <td><input type="text" value='+7 727 390-26-60'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>E-mail* :</td>
              <td><input type="text" value="insi-almaty@mail.ru"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Сообщение* :</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="25" rows="5">Здравствуйте</textarea>               </td>
              <td colspan='2'>
                Вы можете прикрепить к заявке файл(не более 3 мегабайт)<input type="file" name='f_file'></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Задать вопрос</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Заказать звонок</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Оставить отзыв</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Посмотреть исправленный пример](http://jsbin.com/xiqorilu/1/edit)**

Объясняю на пальцах.
У вас 4 блока. Грубо говоря, один под одним.
Что вы делаете с помощью CSS?
**Меняете прозрачность блока.** Заметьте, не убираете, а делаете прозрачным. Соответственно, блок никуда (как слой) не исчезает. Просто теперь можно смотреть сквозь него. Следовательно, вы думаете, что кликнули на блок, который под ним, а кликаете по этому же самому блоку.

Вот пример, чтобы было проще понять:
Вы увидели на витрине пироженое. Хотите взять. Но что за напасть? Ваша рука натыкается на невидимую преграду. В данном случае, стекло. Так и тут.
Как это поправить?

Замените **opacity: 0; и opacity: 1;** на **display: none; и display: block;** соответственно и все заработает.

Comment: спасибо)родина вас не забудет

Answer (score 0):

Поставил Z-index 1000 заработало)

Comment: Теперь вы столкнетесь, скорее всего, с тем, что селекты в других дивах будут некликабельные по той же причине, что и ранее.

Answer (score 0):

У вас дивы, в которых контент, располагаются друг над другом, и див с селектом на самом дне. Поэтому когда вы кликаете по этим дивам, вы всегда кликаете только по верхнему. Делать табы через прозрачные дивы не самая лучшая идея, попробуйте скрывать контент через `display: none;`.